# Não consigo adicionar arquivos .txt em .TAR(C#) .net framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Bom dia!

Quero adicionar os arquivos .txt(conforme imagem abaixo) em .TAR

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]

mas não estou conseguindo. o arquivo .TAR é criado, mas os arquivos não são adicionados. Segue imagem:

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]][2]

Segue código.

```
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.GZip;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar;
using System.IO;

namespace Milhous.Recorder.Homolog.CompressInTar
{
    public class TarCreateFromStream
    {
        public void CreateTar(string outputTarFilename, string sourceDirectory)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputTarFilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            using (Stream gzipStream = new GZipOutputStream(fs))
            using (TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(gzipStream))
            {
                AddDirectoryFilesToTar(tarArchive, sourceDirectory, true);
            }
        }

        private void AddDirectoryFilesToTar(TarArchive tarArchive, string sourceDirectory, bool recurse)
        {
            if (recurse)
            {
                string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory);
                foreach (string directory in directories)
                    AddDirectoryFilesToTar(tarArchive, directory, recurse);
            }


            string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory);
            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                TarEntry tarEntry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(filename);
                tarArchive.WriteEntry(tarEntry, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Olha... a mensagem do erro é bem clara... você tentou executar o código sem estar com esses arquivos abertos em nenhum lugar?

Comment: Não. na verdade o problema mesmo é que não está adicionando os arquivos .txt no .RAR

Comment: Cara, caso a pasta de destino for a mesma de origem. no seu código você tenta adicionar o arquivo `.tar` dentro dele mesmo, enquanto ele está aberto...